Order by Post Title in WP Query not working
Its wired, i've try to order a custom post type simply by title, and still struggle. Of cause i checkt the dWP dev resources and much more. See always the same solutions, but its not working. Maybe I have something around that is the problem.
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'my-ctp-name',
'post_status' => 'publish',
'post_parent' => 0, // show only parents, is needed for my task
'posts_per_page' => -1,
'orderby' => 'title',
'order' => 'ASC'
// Also testes with
// 'orderby' => array( 'title' => 'ASC' ),
// 'orderby' => array( 'post_title' => 'ASC' )
);
$query = new WP_Query($args);
if( $query->have_posts() ){
    while( $query->have_posts() ){
        $query->the_post();
        get_template_part( 'template-parts/archive/archive', get_post_type() );
    }
}else{
   get_template_part( 'template-parts/content/content', 'notfound' );
} 
wp_reset_query();


Seems like you haven't closed the $args array. The closing parenthesis seems to be commented out on this line: // 'orderby' => array( 'post_title' => 'ASC' ));. Try moving the last ); to a new line so it is no longer in the comment.

Thats for your review. You are right, but this was just a mistake while posting the code. I edited now here in the post.

Does your custom post type use page attributes (e.g. menu ordering), or do you use any plugins which may be applying this feature to your CPT? Does the order change if you order descending instead of ascending? Why does the code end with wp_reset_query() when it does not modify the main query? You might take a moment to review the "[ask]" page in our [help], and then edit the question to include any additional information. The CPT registration and an example of the ordered titles would be very useful.
